# JSON Httpresponse in python 3.4

Tags: python, json

I am trying to work with the BTC-E public api. So far I have this:

```
import time
import json
import urllib
import urllib.request

url = 'https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd?ignore_invalid=1'

def main(btce_url = url):
        req = urllib.request.urlopen(btce_url)
        result = json.loads(req.readall().decode('utf-8'))
        print(result)
```

Which returns the whole response. how do I convert the JSON into a list so I can handle individual pieces of info? e.g. last price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import time
import json
import urllib
import urllib.request

url = 'https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd?ignore_invalid=1'

def main(btce_url = url):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(btce_url)
    result = json.loads(req.readall().decode('utf-8'))
    print(result['btc_usd']['low']) # for example ..


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That fixed it, I was actually missing something they changed from API v2 to v3, but thank you!